# Angular2 show every <img> modally when clicked

Tags: angular

I'm trying to show every image (which are in "post-content" class only) modally when someone click on it.

```
<div class="entry-content" [innerHTML]="article.post_content" >
```

Any idea what is the best way to do it?

Comment: Please post what `post_content` contains.

Comment: article.post_content contain html code like <p>Lorem Ipsum</p> <img src="some_image" />